# Bouncy Castle key generation extremely slow on Android

Tags: android, bouncycastle

I have an Android crypto app that's built with Bouncy Castle (actually using Spongy Castle but essentially the same thing). For some reason key generation is EXTREMELY slow (on the order of several minutes).

Here is a test method I'm using:

```
@Test
public void testHMAC()
{
    System.out.println(getTestAnnouncement("testHMAC"));

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final PBEParametersGenerator generator = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator();
    generator.init(PBEParametersGenerator.PKCS5PasswordToBytes(("mypassword").toCharArray()), new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }, 8192);
    byte[] key = ((KeyParameter)generator.generateDerivedParameters(256)).getKey();

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    Assert.assertTrue("Generated " + key.length + "-byte key, took " + time + "ms", true);
}
```

When I run this on my 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo machine, it takes around 0.05 seconds (50 ms). When I run that same method on Android, it takes **several hundred thousand** milliseconds (i.e. ~3-5 **minutes**).

I'm running it on an HTC Thunderbolt running Android 2.2.1. The application targets 2.1, if that makes any difference (I remember reading something about < 2.2 not having JIT but I assume the app target would make no difference, as long as the actual OS on the phone is >= 2.2). This is a pretty powerful phone which has a 1 GHz Snapdragon processor, and it seems strange that generating a key would take that many orders of magnitude longer than on a PC. What are possible causes of this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jake, although the tracing JIT should work well with Crypto library, can you try doing this with the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)? From what I've heard, even after the JIT, the performance improvement on the NDK is significant. (Of the order of 10-50x)

Comment: I tried this with the NDK using Botan... decrypted the file in < 1000 ms (didn't measure). I've just decided to just write the core of my app in C++/Qt with Necessitas so this isn't too much of an issue for me. I wonder if BlackBerry's crypto libraries are using JNI to a native crypto implementation - either way I hope its Java implementation is better than Android's because we CAN'T use C++ there until BB10...